# React not finding a .cache/default_development file when re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I encountered this problem while I was coding a component on React.

I built this react app using `npx create-react-app`.

When I run 'npm start' the application boots up and I can make updated in realtime without refreshing, but sometimes when I update the code I get this error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/myprofile/Desktop/WorkTable/MyProject/client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/4.pack'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/myprofile/Desktop/WorkTable/MyProject/client/node_modules/.cache/default-development/4.pack'
}
```

For now, I have three files: `App.js`, `LoginForm.js` and `RegisterForm.js`, the last two are built in the same way, one has just one input more.

This is `App.js`:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate, } from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';
import LoginForm from './components/auth/LoginForm';
import RegisterForm from './components/auth/RegisterForm';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/auth/login' element= {
            <LoginForm/>
          }/>
          <Route path='/auth/register' element= {
            <RegisterForm/>
          }/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

while this is `LoginForm.js`:

```
function LoginForm () {
    return (
        <div className='form_container'>
            <div className="background">
                <div className="shape"></div>
                <div className="shape"></div>
            </div>
            <form className='login_form'>
                <h2>Login Here</h2>

                <div className='input_container'>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email"></input>
                </div>

                <div className='input_container'>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"></input>
                </div>

                <button>Log In</button>
                <p className='alternatives_p'>or Sign Up using</p>
                <div className="social">
                <div className="go"><i className="fab fa-google"></i>Google</div>
                <div className="fb"><i className="fab fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LoginForm;
```

The function that throws the error is:
`node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19`

I add the function and its comment so maybe it is easier to understand the problem:

```
// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});
```

It doesn't happen every time so I'm not sure what is making this happen. At first it seemed that updating a file and refreshing the page before React automatically doing it was the reason of this error, as I tried doing it sometimes and the error occurred, but then it started doing it also when I just update a file and wait for React to re-render the document.